# Break the Flow of build and include a task in Gradle Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio,
I have a task, called abc.
I want that task to run that task once the Java files in the Android are converted into class files , [That task modifies those class files] ,  such that these class files are used by the Android studio to build the APK.

I heard transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug is the task which compiles those Java Files, but When I do transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug.finalizedBy("abc")
I get the error

Could not get unknown property 'transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
abc.dependsOn(transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug)
```

Then execute "abc" task manually:

```
$ ./gradlew abc
```

Comment: No it didn't work, I want to make abc to run when gradle build is executed, provided abc executes before transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug